# Real Time Functionlity with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, node.js

I am working on attendance system where project management system is also handling using Javascript\Jquery at client side and PHP\MySQL at server side.

A feature in my web app is **user message to admin. For this I have applied an ajax request which is made by setTimeout function (after every 15 seconds) to check that is there any new message comes in database if yes then return it to the admin.**

It working fine but the drawback is (as you know) **continuous request to server** which really poor and bad. As I know that real time functionality can solve this problem I have checked some link **websocket.io and signlR** but there are applicable with Nodejs and asp.net.
So, how can I apply real time functionality with php or I get that new data have reached in to database without continues request with ajax.

Comment: There's always [server sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) if you just need to check the DB on the server

Comment: @adeneo And if you don't have any IE users... http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually some PHP tools for doing this now. For instance, check out [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

It's also possible to do bi-directional sockets by creating a simple TCP/IP server. I've done this before for bi-directional communication between a PHP server and a desktop app.

http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php